# Accessing universal-cookie set by React from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, react-redux

My ReactJS app creates an `httpOnly` universal-cookie with the token after the user logs in. The code is as follows,

```
cookies.set('token', res.data.token, { path: '/', httpOnly: true });
```

In my NodeJS backend code, I am trying to access this cookie by using the following code,

```
const cookies = req.universalCookies.get('token')
```

When I `console.log` the cookies variable it shows `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Is there any better and safe method that works? If yes then please let me know about that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js cannot access the cookie because it is server-side. You can solve it by sending a token from the Header.